# What do I need to upgrade to make my laptop faster?

Tags: laptop, memory, adobe-photoshop, lenovo-laptop

Alright, I'll try to be as brief as possible.

I bought a used Lenovo T440S (Touch). I use a lot of Adobe applications (photo-editing, video-editing). It works fine for the most part but the poor thing is always getting pushed to its limits. I want to know if there is a way to change that without spending too much money.

**Detailed specifications (CPU-Z) & Usage:**
[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mykl0.jpg)
[Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE3gx.jpg)
Storage: 512 GB HDD
[SPD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QEoe.jpg)
[Graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNUTU.jpg)
[Applications I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBd79.jpg)

In case the images don't open, the specifications are Intel i7 4600U 2.10GHz, 8 GB DDR3 RAM, Intel HD Graphics Family (1 GB).

I was thinking of upgrading the RAM to 16 GB DDR3. Is that a good decision? What suggestions do you have?

Comment: Before upgrading RAM I would recommend switching to an SSD.

Comment: Adobe is GPU accelerated, an since you don't have a discrete GPU you won't be able to accelerate it much.  If you had a good AMD or NVIDIA GPU that would help significantly, but since you have a laptop that can't be upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laptops are not very up-gradable overall; the motherboards are normally proprietary to that specific model, so that can't be upgraded and the video is built in, so that can't be upgraded normally. Since the motherboard can't be upgraded, the CPU generally can only get a small upgrade (unless you are running the fastest stated to work for that model) and you are limited on the number of memory slots.

In your particular case, the CPU is already faster than the CPUs [their website](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t440s/) states that model supports. This particular laptop does support 16GB.

This basically only leaves two options for upgrade:

1. Hard Drive - an SSD would definitely be a great upgrade; actually the best upgrade I had done in years to my computers. It is far more noticeable than any upgrade you are going to do.
2. Memory - Sure, 16GB is great, but do you need it? Check your current used memory while using the laptop; if you aren't maxing it out, more memory won't help.

As it stands, your laptop model is 5 years old (from what I could find); if the SSD upgrade doesn't make you happy, I would recommend buying a new laptop.